# Excel: What to multiply by to get a specific result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, divide, multiplication

How do I make a formula that calculates what to multiply by in order to get a specific result?

Let's say I want to bet 100 at odds 2. This gives me 200, with a profit of 100.
What if the odds is 3 (or any other number). How much would I have to be to keep a profit of 100?

It sounds really simple, but I just can't figure it out...

Comment: "How do I make a formula that calculates what to multiply by in order to get a specific result?" Division?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is simply a math question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `k` (e.g. 2 or 3) you want to solve the equation `kx - x = 100`. But this is just `(k-1)x = 100` so `x = 100/(k-1)`. If the odds (`k`) are in cell `A1` and the target profit (e.g. 100) is in cell `A2` then in cell `A3` you can put the formula `=A2/(A1-1)`. Obviously, you don't have to use those specific cells.

Comment: Thank you. And please excuse my poor math skillss, but how do I turn that into a formula I can use in Excel?